# Android - Is there a callback function when a View is all set?

Tags: android, view, callback

I have a `custom View`, in which I need to perform treatment that require that the size of the view is set (so `onCreate` doesn't works), but before displaying anything. So I wondered if there is a callback function tat I could override for that ?

Right now I'm using `onLayout`, but it seems to be called twice, so I'm assuming it's probably not the right use for this. I also tried doing it in `onMeasure` but it seems that `getWidth()` and `getHeight` still `returns 0` in it.

Thkanks,

Robin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `OnGlobalLayoutListener` inside `onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = yourView.getViewTreeObserver();
    if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
      viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            viewWidth = yourView.getWidth();
          viewHeight = yourView.getHeight();
            yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
          System.out.println(viewHeight + " on resume x" + yourView.getX()); 
        }
      });
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback [OnSizeChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

Answer (score 0):

use onSizeChanged,

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldwidth, int oldheight) {
    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldwidth, oldheight);
    // your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try those methods

```
 1.
ViewTreeObserver vto2 = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto2.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new

OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout () {
        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        int height = imageView.getHeight();
        int width = imageView.getWidth();
        textView.append("\n\n" + imageView.getHeight() + "," + imageView.getWidth());
    }
}

);

2.

imageView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        int h = imageView.getHeight();
        int w = imageView.getWidth();
        Log.i(TAG, "Height=" + h);
    }
};
```